# I can not work with Single-Node Kubernetes Installation with Vagrant & CoreOS

Tags: docker, vagrant, kubernetes, kubectl

I have been executed through the https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant-single.html document but have been unable to execute,

kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 172.17.4.99:443 was refused - did you prescribed the right host or port?

My configuration：

```
myhtlsdeMacBook-Pro:single-node myhtls$ kubectl config set-cluster vagrant-single-cluster --server=https://172.17.4.99:443 --certificate-authority=${PWD}/ssl/ca.pem

Cluster "vagrant-single-cluster" set.

myhtlsdeMacBook-Pro:single-node myhtls$ kubectl config set-credentials vagrant-single-admin --certificate-authority=${PWD}/ssl/ca.pem --client-key=${PWD}/ssl/admin-key.pem --client-certificate=${PWD}/ssl/admin.pem

User "vagrant-single-admin" set.

myhtlsdeMacBook-Pro:single-node myhtls$ kubectl config set-context vagrant-single --cluster=vagrant-single-cluster --user=vagrant-single-admin
Context "vagrant-single" set.

myhtlsdeMacBook-Pro:single-node myhtls$  kubectl config use-context vagrant-single

Switched to context "vagrant-single".
```

my docker ps,Do not see the mirror running.

I also did not see the downloaded Kubernetes, dns, heapster, etc these images。

Answer (score 0):

Have you waited a few minutes as the docs suggests?

> NOTE: When the cluster is first being launched, it must download all container images for the cluster components (Kubernetes, dns, heapster, etc). Depending on the speed of your connection, it can take a few minutes before the Kubernetes api-server is available. Before the api-server is running, the kubectl command above may show output similar to:
>
> The connection to the server 172.17.4.99:443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: Sorry, these days something went to the place where there is no network。yes,I waited for a long time did not see any reaction? I do not know which step to start downloading.